# Figure Canvas widget not showing up

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm trying to embed a matplotlib animation into my PyQt5-GUI. Here's my class of the animation:

```
class AnimationCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.fig.set_facecolor('#1a1a1a')

        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111,polar=True)
        self.ax.set_facecolor('#333333')
        self.ax.set_ylim(0,1)
        self.ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=8,colors='#ffffff')
        self.ax.set_yticks([])  # Shows no r values
        self.ax.set_xticks(np.pi/180. * np.linspace(0,  360, 18, endpoint=False)) # A line every 20 degrees
        self.ax.grid(color='#595959', linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.7)
        self.ax.set_title("Position of the speakers", pad = 8,
                          fontdict= dict(
                              color = '#ffffff',
                              fontsize = 15,
                              fontweight = 0.9))
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([], [], marker = 'X', color= '#ffffe6',markersize=15)

        super(AnimationCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)
```

When I use the following code in a MainWindow class (that handles the animation) to set it as a central widget it shows, no problem there. But I want to embed it into my existing GUI so that it's not the central widget. When I try to give it an absolute position by using `setGeometry()` or `move()`, it just doesn't show up anymore. I've also tried using QVBoxLayout and adding `self.canvas` to the layout, that works too, but I don't know how to stylize it properly so that it doesn't look like a huge mess with those unwanted whitespaces.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,xdata, *args, **kwargs,):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        widget = QWidget()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(widget)

        self.canvas = AnimationCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
        vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.angles = xdata*(3.14/180)
        self.ydata = np.ones(len(self.angles))*0.96
        self.index = 0
        self.line = self.canvas.line

        self.plot_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.canvas)
        self.plot_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 5, 50, 25))
        self.plot_button.setText("plot")
        self.plot_button.setObjectName("plot")
        self.plot_button.clicked.connect(self.plot_animation)
        vbox.addWidget(self.plot_button)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 600)
```

Questions:

1. Why doesn't `setGeometry()` work in this instance and how to fix it.
2. If I have to use QVBoxLayout, what's the best way to achieve a nice look? `addSpacing()` and `addStretch()` everywhere seems like a bit of an overkill to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) please provide a [mre], 2) Please show a picture of what you get and what you want to get to understand yourself better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place your AnimationCanvas directly on the central widget then call `setParent` in the constructor.

```
class AnimationCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        ...
        super(AnimationCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
```

And construct the AnimationCanvas with parent `widget`, the central widget of the QMainWindow. The call to `setGeometry` on the QPushButton will now work, it will be placed on the AnimationCanvas at position (5, 5) with the size (50, 25).

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,xdata=None, *args, **kwargs,):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.canvas = AnimationCanvas(parent=widget, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)

        self.plot_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.canvas)
        self.plot_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 5, 50, 25))

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 600)
```

If you use a layout then `setGeometry` will usually be ignored because the layout manages the position and size of all its widgets. However, you could add only the AnimationCanvas to the layout and not the QPushButton, allowing it to stay on the AnimationCanvas with the exact geometry you specify.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,xdata=None, *args, **kwargs,):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(widget)

        self.canvas = AnimationCanvas(width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.plot_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.canvas)
        self.plot_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 5, 50, 25))

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 600)
```